# Nginx : redirect path to subdomain and keep end of path and params

Tags: redirect, nginx, subdomain

My goal is to redirect this kind of url:

```
http://example.com/cloud/signup?format=json
```

to:

```
http://services.example.com/users/create?format=json
```

So I want to:

- remove the folder /cloud
- add a subdomain "services"
- change the end of url
- keep GET/POST/PUT params if there are some

My current test is:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        server_name services.example.com;
        passenger_enabled on;
        rails_env    production;
        root         /home/admin/app/current/public;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
}

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com;
        location ~ /cloud(.*) {
                return 301 $scheme://services.example.com/users/create?format=json;
        }
}
```

It doesn't work.
Does I need to create 2 servers or can I do a redirect with just the main server ?

Comment: You can't keep post/put on redirect

Comment: Maybe it's possible using this tip: http://serverfault.com/questions/312111/how-do-i-get-nginx-to-forward-http-post-requests-via-rewrite

Comment: Yes. But it will not be rediirect. It will be reverse proxy

Comment: OK. As it is a Rails app, I think I will try to make my redirects in Rails routes file.